# GSON deserialize json value to Java object

Tags: java, json, gson

I have following json object:

```
{
    "aSize": 1,
    "aPrice": 1,
    "aName": "Ticket",
    "aDescription": "Tickets are required to unlock the story"
}
```

And Java Object:

```
public class Item
{
    private String   aId;  
    private int      aSize;  
    private Currency aPrice;   
    private String   aName; 
    private String   aDescription;
}

public class Currency
{
    private int aPrice;
}
```

When i try to deserialize the Item object i get this error:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: 1

I don't want to change `aPrice` into Json object.

The question is - can I somehow tell GSON to construct Currency object from a Json value other than to create deserializer for whole Item class?

Comment: By Currency you mean `java.util.Currency` or a self created class?

Comment: It's custom class. I've updated my question.

Comment: Why wouldn't you create a custom deserializer?

Comment: Because i'm lazy and I don't want to create a deserializer for whole class, if there is a way to somehow mark the field to magically construct an object. That's what the whole question about :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should create an `ItemDeserializer` class which implements `JsonDeserializer` interface.

```
import com.google.gson.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class ItemDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Item> {

    public Item deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException 
    {  
        JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setaName(jsonObject.get("aName").getAsString());
        item.setaSize(jsonObject.get("aSize").getAsInt());
        item.setaPrice(new Currency(jsonObject.get("aPrice").getAsInt()));
        item.setaDescription(jsonObject.get("aDescription").getAsString());
        return item;
    }
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        String json = "{ \"aSize\": 1, \"aPrice\": 1, \"aName\": " +
                "\"Ticket\", \"aDescription\": \"Tickets are required to unlock the story\" }";
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        ItemDeserializer itemDeserializer = new ItemDeserializer();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Item.class, itemDeserializer);
        Gson customGson = gsonBuilder.create();
        Item item = customGson.fromJson(json, Item.class);
        System.out.println(item);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in my question i stated that I don't want to create deserializer for whole `Item` class.

Comment: Probably it would be wiser than to use Jackson instead of GSON with `@JsonSerialize(using = CustomCurrencySerializer.class)` annotation. And you have to implement the serializer for the `Currency`.